# Is it possible to use allure in a C++ test environment?

Tags: c++, allure

I was wondering if Allure would allow me to create reports out of C++ code.

Searching for it did not return much; I see that Allure support a lot of test frameworks but can't see anything specific for C++

Comment: The problem is that Allure don't actually have a C++ developer in the team, so feel free to create an adaptor for any framework you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allure 2 supports results in junit.xml format. It is just about the release, but you can try out BETA8 (available to download [here](https://bintray.com/qameta/generic/allure2/2.0-BETA8)). Usage: `$ allure serve --profile junit junit/results/path` or `$ allure generate --profile junit junit/results/path`

Answer (score 0):

Allure unfortunately dos'nt provide anything specific for C++.

I found it for C# though.

https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp-commons

Thanks

Comment: I had that feeling; the official page mention nothing about C++